# Required content for platform android is missing reinstall xcode

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter app that I want to build the iOS. I Just bought a MacBook Air, OS Catalina v. 10.15.6 just for that. I have been struggling since this week just to install the Xcode from website or App Store, I am still getting an error when I open the Xcode saying: *required content for platform android is missing. Please reinstall Xcode*

[image]

I reinstalled Xcode 3 times already, so this is not the issue.

When I run `flutter doctor`, I first have a dialog saying: git command requires the command line develop tools.... and this is the output in Terminal:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
 
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
    ✗ Xcode requires additional components to be installed in order to run.
      Launch Xcode and install additional required components when prompted or
      run:
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with
        is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see
        https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Does someone know what is wrong here, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup xcode according to this: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#ios-setup

Comment: What happens when you try to run your app from Xcode?

Comment: A dialog saying : Required content for platform android is missing. Please reinstall Xcode... take a look at the image attached to my post